# How to prevent entering more input than required in C?

Tags: c

I want the user to enter only two integers, and no more than two. The user should enter two integers separated by spaces. So, for example:

1. The valid input is: 1 2
2. Invalid input: 1 2 3

```c
#include<stdio.h>  
     int main(){
       int a;
       int b;
       printf("Enter input:\n");
       int numbers = scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
       if(numbers != 2){
            printf("Invalid input.\n");
            }
    else{   printf("First: %d Second: %d\n", a, b);
     }  return 0;
    }
```

If I enter more than 2 integers, the program accepts the first 2 integers and ignores the third. In this case, I want to print an error, but the program still ends.
So my question is, what should I do to achieve my needs?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `scanf` is doing what it's supposed to. The user has entered three numbers, but `scanf` has only consumed two of them. If you used `scanf` to read another number, it would consume that third one.

You should probably be using [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to consume an entire *line* of input, then using [sscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to read out the two numbers, then if it finds the two, you can check for more to validate your input.

Comment: And here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bq1e136Ms) to show how this could look.